# Break string into individual fields in R

Tags: r, nlp, stringr

I have the string

`She was the youngest of the two daughters of a most affectionate`

and I want to turn this into a vector like below

`she` `was` `the` `youngest` etc.

I'd like to use stringr if possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the following could work:

```
scan(text=charv, what = character())
 [1] "She"          "was"          "the"          "youngest"     "of"           "the"         
 [7] "two"          "daughters"    "of"           "a"            "most"         "affectionate"
```

or

```
unlist(strsplit(charv,' '))

 [1] "She"          "was"          "the"          "youngest"     "of"           "the"         
 [7] "two"          "daughters"    "of"           "a"            "most"         "affectionate"
```

or

```
read.table(text=gsub(' ','\n',charv))
             V1
1           She
2           was
3           the
4      youngest
5            of
6           the
7           two
8     daughters
9            of
10            a
11         most
12 affectionate
```

or

```
 unlist(regmatches(charv,gregexpr('\\w+',charv)))
 [1] "She"          "was"          "the"          "youngest"     "of"           "the"         
 [7] "two"          "daughters"    "of"           "a"            "most"         "affectionate"
```

Where:

```
 charv<-'She was the youngest of the two daughters of a most affectionate'
```

EDIT: using stringr:
Any of the following

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(charv, '\\w+')
str_split(charv," ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
charv <- 'She was the youngest of the two daughters of a most affectionate'

#Code
x <- do.call(c,strsplit(charv,split = ' '))

[1] "She"          "was"          "the"          "youngest"     "of"           "the"          "two"         
[8] "daughters"    "of"           "a"            "most"         "affectionate"
```

Comment: Yes, I do this, and then I have to do `as.data.frame()` to get it into a dataframe. I tried `str_remove(charv, " ")`, but had a hard time accessing the elements inside. Thank you

Comment: `str_split()` is also available @DanielJachetta

Comment: @DanielJachetta As you have said a vector. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: To be more concise, `strsplit(charv,split = ' ')[[1]]` is ok!